# What is the order of construction calls in Matlab OOP?

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor

I have a subclass and super that I'm working with that looks similar to this:

```
classdef ClassSub < ClassSuper
    properties
        prop2
    end

    methods
        function self = ClassSub(Param1, Param2)
            self = ClassSuper(Param1);
            self.prop2 = Param2;
        end
    end
end

classdef ClassSuper
    properties
        prop1
    end

    methods
        function self = ClassSuper(Param1)
            self.prop1 = Param1;
        end
    end
end
```

When I go to create a new subclass: `test = ClassSub(1,2);` I'm getting the following error:

> Not enough input arguments.

As I step through the code, I noticed that before the constructor for the subclass is called, the supers is called, **with zero input arguments** and then the sub classes constructor is called, and then finally the super's is called once again.  What is supposed to be the normal order of construction call for a sub class?  If it's this, is there a way to force the subclasses's constructor first, who then calls the supers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax to [call superclass constructor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html) is:

```
classdef ClassSub < ClassSuper
    %# ...
    methods
        function self = ClassSub(Param1, Param2)
            self = self@ClassSuper(Param1);
            self.prop2 = Param2;
        end
    end
end
```